# Nlog Config: override general rules

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nlog

This is my nlog config from appsettings.json:

```
"rules": [
  {
    "logger": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*",
    "minLevel": "Error",
    "writeTo": "console"
  },
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Info",
    "writeTo": "console"
  }
]
```

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     
     var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddNLog());
     optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
}
```

I would like to log all logs with minLevel info to console, but for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.* I would like to log only Errors and Fatals.

Could you explain me, what I am doing wrong, because info level messages are being logged to console too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NLog v5 then you can use [FinalMinLevel](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel):

```json
"rules": [
  {
    "logger": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*",
    "finalMinLevel": "Error"
  },
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Info",
    "writeTo": "console"
  }
]
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules